# Outer bound type declarations without ScopedTypeVariables

Tags: haskell

I have a following working definition:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Control.Retry where

import Prelude hiding (catch)
import Control.Exception
import Control.Concurrent

retrying [] action = action 
retrying (i:is) action = catch action processError
  where 
    processError (e :: IOException) = threadDelay i >> retrying is action
```

Just out of curiosity I am wondering how I could reimplement this without utilizing the `ScopedTypeVariables` pragma, or whether I could at all, and what the inferred type declaration of `processError` actually is, because specifying `processError :: IOException -> IO a` makes it uncompilable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to avoid `ScopedTypeVariables`, you can most of the time use `asTypeOf`.

```
retrying [] action = action 
retrying (i:is) action = catch action processError
  where 
    processError e = snd (e `asTypeOf` (undefined :: IOException), threadDelay i >> retrying is action)
```

The `undefined :: IOException` is an expression type signature, and that is allowed by the standard. The `asTypeOf` requires the exception `e` to be an `IOException`.

I would prefer `ScopedTypeVariables` here, though.

With

```
retrying :: [Int] -> IO a -> IO a
```

the type of `processError` is inferred as

```
processError :: IOException -> IO a
```

with the `a` here being the same type variable as in the signature of `retrying`. That type can, however, not be specified in Haskell without the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension, since type variables in written-down signatures are by default universally quantified.

Comment: Thanks. But what about the type signature of `processError` - how does it bind the type of `action` to the outer function?

Comment: `processError` can't have a type signature without `ScopedTypeVariables`. In its inferred type, using `action` from the enclosing scope dtermines its result type as `IO whatever_the_result_type_of_retrying_is`. So, given `retrying :: [Int] -> IO a -> IO a`, the inferred type of `processError` is `processError :: IOException -> IO a`. But you cannot write down that type without STV.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any fancy name for this trick that a lambda calculus mathematician would use?

Comment: @Tarrasch I have no idea if it's widespread enough to have a name.

Answer (score 7):

Another option, maybe a little cleaner than asTypeOf:

```
retrying [] action = action 
retrying (i:is) action = catch action processError                                                                                                                                
  where
    processError e = threadDelay i >> retrying is action
      where
        _ = e :: IOException
```

Not sure if this is idiomatic; I just made it up and it worked.

Comment: I've seen this mostly in the context of quickcheck tests, where you see the idiom `where _types = (foo :: A, bar :: B)`

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
retrying [] action = action 
retrying (i:is) action = catch action $ processError $
                         threadDelay i >> retrying is action
  where
    processError :: IO a -> IOException -> IO a
    processError foo e = foo
```

Basically, this takes care of the problem of doing `processError :: IOException -> IO a`, where the `a` is generic and not the same `a` as in the enclosing function, by taking in an argument with the type `a` in it in order to tie it to the type in the enclosing function.