# Referring to an existential type variable

Tags: haskell, existential-type

I would like to add type signatures to some local functions in my code.  However, their types involve anonymous, existentially bound type variables.  Since they're anonymous, I don't know how to write a type signature.  How can I refer to such type variables?

In the following example, `go` has type `[b] -> Int -> Int`, where `b` is the type bound by the pattern match `T (x_shared:xs) g`.  What type signature can I write for it?

```hs
data T = forall a. T [a] (a -> a -> Int)

f :: T -> Int
f (T (x_shared:xs) g) = go xs 0
  where
    -- go :: what type?
    go (x:xs) n = go xs $! n + g x_shared x
    go []     n = n
```

Comment: You mightfind this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828602/outer-bound-type-declarations-without-scopedtypevariables

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With `ScopedTypeVariables` extension, you can add a type annotation to `g` and introduce type variable `a` to the scope.

```
f (T (x_shared:xs) (g :: a -> a -> Int)) = go xs 0
```

Then you can write a type signature for `go` with `a`.

```
go :: [a] -> Int -> Int
```

Comment: I didn't know you could introduce type variables in patterns!  You learn something knew every day, I guess.